# Android :delete item from grid view after drag and drop

Tags: android, object, gridview, drag-and-drop

i try to drag and drop item between 2 grid view, when i drop it, the item correctly added to the destination list but it's not deleted from the source list.
this is my function

```
            @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {


            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                    PassObject passObj = (PassObject)event.getLocalState();
                    View view = passObj.view;
                    Artifact passedItem = passObj.artifact;
                    List<Artifact> srcList = passObj.srcList;
                    AbsListView oldParent = (AbsListView)view.getParent();
                    ArtifactAdapter srcAdapter = (ArtifactAdapter) oldParent.getAdapter();

                    LinearLayoutAbsListView newParent = (LinearLayoutAbsListView)v;
                    ArtifactAdapter destAdapter = (ArtifactAdapter)(newParent.absListView.getAdapter());
                    List<Artifact> destList = destAdapter.getList();

                    srcList.remove(passedItem);
                    addItemToList(destList, passedItem);



                    srcAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    destAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //smooth scroll to bottom
                    newParent.absListView.smoothScrollToPosition(destAdapter.getCount()-1);

                    break;


            return true;
        }

    };
```

can somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

Make `case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:` and then remove the item from the original grid. `ACTION_DROP` is called from the other grid view with different context.

If you are 100% sure that the moment `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` gets fired you need to remove the item use `ACTION_DRAG_STARTED` instead.

Remember in which event which element uses the adapter in which context. Your call `srcList.remove(passedItem);` may not be in right context (Activity, Fragment, FragmentActivity...etc)

Comment: i obtain the same result :/

Comment: Make sure that your `passedItem != null` and you call `revalidate()` at somewhere relevant place to update the UI components.
**EDIT:**Best practise is to mark the UI components that are "dirty" and needs update with `invalidate()` and when you need to "clean" those "dirty" parts use `validate()`. `revalidate()` makes your current UI component "dirty" and "cleans" it at the same moment.

Comment: in fact, i can remove the item with the position (remove(positionOfpassedItem)), i don't know why i can't use (remove(passedItem)). i will use that

Comment: That's because removing by index is little bit easier rather than by first searching the object and then removing it.